# Docker Error creating external connectivity network

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

i am trying to deploy a portainer/agent stack with the recommended docker compose configuration as suggested in the official documentation (https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/agent.html), and it deploys and runs correctly on all the nodes except for 1.

on the node that fails, i check the error and it says:

```
starting container failed: error creating external connectivity network: could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among the defaults to assign to the network
```

this is strange because this is a latest installation of raspbian. and i have just installed docker using the script from the official raspberry pi website (https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/docker-comes-to-raspberry-pi/). this is how docker has been set up on the other raspberry pi's too (the other raspberry pi's are working fine).

the docker compose file is:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  agent:
    image: portainer/agent
    environment:
      AGENT_CLUSTER_ADDR: tasks.agent
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - target: 9001
        published: 9001
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    networks:
      - portainer_agent
    deploy:
      mode: global

networks:
  portainer_agent:
    driver: overlay
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a Docker issue, last time I hitted this error I had to reboot my Docker host to fix it and be able to create a container.

I was using an old version of Docker though, might have been fixed since.

Comment: i have rebooted many times and tried upgrading my docker version many times trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you have used all the available networks in your pool of subnet spaces. For overlay networks, you can limit the available address pools with the `--default-addr-pool` option on `docker swarm init` which you'll see under the Swarm section of `docker info`. Once docker has allocated all the subnets from that pool, you'll need to delete networks to free up space in the pool (or create your swarm with a bigger pool, I'm not aware of a way to change this setting after creating the swarm).

Note that if a subnet is routeable, docker will treat it like an allocated network, so beware of things like VPN's that create a large route that includes all the private networks.